# Records duplicated in Crystal Report after integrated with application

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I have designed a crystal report file. When i generating a report using preview option in crystal report. Report displayed distinct records (Database menu > select distinct records). I have integrated that report in my Java application. But when i generating a report in application, records are duplicated.

please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adamant that's the reason what appear to be duplicate records are appearing?

I would recommend you run a trace on the server when you run the report in Crystal. Then run a trace when you run the report in your Java application. Are the query's different?